How to recover data from entire ext4 disk wiped (now unallocated)
While going through a routine install of nixos the installer swapped sda and sdb. I made the mistake of not taking note of the disk size and ran the installer to entire wipe and install on the wrong disk. Luckily I hope, it failed directly after the wipe. So I am left with the unallocated status on the drive. It was ext4. The original linux system install is wiped too. Is there any way to recover data from entire disk deleted? It has not been mounted or written to since.
Thanks for any help

Just restore from backup.

Ahh yes. In a perfect world.

If you know what the partition table was, and there were no writes over any of the filesystems, you can recreate the parittion table with your favorite partitioning tool (fdisk, parted, etc.) and it will just work.
If you don't know what the partition table was, you can use a tool like TestDisk to scan the drive for partitions and build a new partition table.
Here is the relevant portion of the documentation: Partition Recovery
Unfortunately the process is too involved to fully document within the answer here, but partition recovery is most likely to work and get your filesystems back.

First, thank you for your reply. So I think you are saying if I boot gparted and highlight the disk and create new partition on the disk (it was sdb1) I should be able to get it back?

Yes, but you need to match the offsets exactly for the start and end of each partition which was lost. If you don't know that, then you should use a recovery tool instead, such as testdisk.

Hi. Well, I used testdisk. Found the partition and went to write it and rebooted, but it didn't save any of the data unfortunately. Luckily I'm only out about 10 days of backups. Sound just a format and we'll go from there. Nothing mission critical. Thanks again.
